# How to use Sql type of queries against XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

```
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("MoviesData.xml"));
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
xmlreader.Close();
if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
{
    DataList1.Visible = true;
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

I want the specific information from the XML file like moviename, movie description, actors, genres. as well as i want to use the like operator wants to check based upon the user input into textbox how to check it i am not understanding can somebody help me.

Comment: No specific question? Read : [Basic Queries (LINQ to XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dataset.Tables[0].Select("names like  '%" & TextBox.Text & "%'")
```

Or

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\MoviesData.xml");
```

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/query-an-xml-document-using-linq-to-xml/